# Writeup of reverse engineering VM based obfuscation

Tags: obfuscation

I've seen quite a few crackmes on reverse engineering VM's. I've also come across "Unpacking Virtualization Obfuscators". Are there any other writeups that you could point me to that discuss the RE'ing of a VM based obfuscation from scratch?

Also, is the source code for any VM based obfuscator available online?

Comment: Check out **[google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=virtualization+obfuscation)** and source code of **[x86-virtualizer](https://code.google.com/p/x86-virtualizer/)**

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [pretty old challenge](http://old.honeynet.org/scans/scan33/index.html) with, among other stuff, a VM in the end. You have both the write-ups of many candidates, and the [official write-up of the author](http://old.honeynet.org/scans/scan33/nico/index.html), with explanations as how to do such VM-based obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion of reverse engineering virtualization-based obfuscation [here](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/debray/tmp/deobfuscation.pdf).  A forerunner of this work, which in retrospect I'm not all that happy with, was published in ACM CCS 11 [[link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2046739)].

I don't know of source-code availability of any VM-based obfuscators.  There's a free system called Tigress, available (in binary form) from 
http://tigress.cs.arizona.edu/, that performs virtualization at the C source-code level.  This system gives you a lot of control over a lot of the parameters of the obfuscator so you can experiment with different combinations of settings.  The FAQ explains the rationale for not distributing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [article](http://static.usenix.org/event/woot09/tech/full_papers/rolles.pdf) wrote by [Rolf Rolles](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/182/rolf-rolles) about it.